# conver JSON Object to ListOf in Kotlin

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

Hello everyone I want to convert JSON API to ListOf Kotlin how I can convert?
I am using the Volley library
this is JSON API https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos

List Should be like =>

```
                        val imagesList = listOf(
                        R.drawable.designer,
                        R.drawable.image,
                        R.drawable.image,
                        R.drawable.designer,
                        R.drawable.image,
                        R.drawable.image,
                        R.drawable.designer,
                        R.drawable.image,
                        R.drawable.image,
                        R.drawable.designer,
                        R.drawable.image,
                        R.drawable.image,
                        R.drawable.designer,
                        R.drawable.image,
                    )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Am, what?
You have to use a structure "data class" to convert JSON to Kotlin, but R.drawable.image - it's Int object (drawable ID constantly changes as new files are added). You will be destoy your app after first change a folder "Resourses". Store pictures on the server

Comment: R.drawable.image only for example and i am not using class

Comment: Please help me how i can